# First element in a div is off-center

Tags: css

(this line is because SO was chopping parts off...)

Dear *element-in-a-div*,

Why oh why must you be ever so maddeningly off center?

I'm using the following stylesheet:

```
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #tags {
        margin: auto;
    }

    .tag {
        margin: auto;
    }
```

The greyish words are of the `tag` class, and the (invisible) box around them has the id `tags`.

I can't for the life of me think why "est", in this case, would be ever so slightly off center - any help much appreciated!

Thanks.

**The picture**:

[image: Off-Center Madness]

Why oh why must you be ever so maddeningly off center?

I'm using the following stylesheet:

```
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #tags {
        margin: auto;
    }

    .tag {
        margin: auto;
    }
```

The greyish words are of the `tag` class, and the (invisible) box around them has the id `tags`.

I can't for the life of me think why "est", in this case, would be ever so slightly off center - any help much appreciated!

Thanks.

**The picture**:

[image: Off-Center Madness]

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to have a specific width for elements to center them. From the code you supplied, it looks like you haven't specify the width of the div or the image.

Comment: Well, each word is an individual span - there is no fixed image. I have tried setting the width of the div to some fixed value, but that doesn't seem to change anything.